# IDE errors for fake script in visual studio

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have fake build scripts, quite a lot of them, they all work, but visual studio always complains slightly about them.

They all start roughly like this...

```
#r "paket:
nuget Fake.IO.FileSystem
nuget Fake.DotNet.MSBuild
nuget Fake.DotNet.Nuget
nuget Fake.DotNet.Cli
nuget Fake.Runtime
nuget Fake.Core.Target //"
#load "./.fake/build.fsx/intellisense.fsx"
```

and visual studio will complain.

"illegal characters in path" on line 1
"could not resolve this reference. Could not locate assembly "Mono.Posix"...."

Its not a big deal, but its irritating.

Answer (score 1):

Are you dependent on the framework or language version? If not, starting with F# 5 you can likely [simplify the syntax](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5/#package-references-in-f-scripts):

```ml
#r "nuget: Fake.IO.FileSystem"
#r "nuget: Fake.DotNet.MSBuild"
...
```

This should also remove VS warnings, at least it did in my case. Make sure you use VS that supports new F# then.

Comment: assembly reference nuget fake.io.filesystem was not found or invalid, and if I run the script, this is the latest vs

Comment: oo, the above doesnt make sense, sorry...but yes, I still get the issue, and the script no longer runs

Comment: Does this approach work for you in general though? Maybe there is an issue with the particular package. Is [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/) the one btw?

Comment: I completely take it back, I was missing a ":" after the nuget...it ALMOST works, the error goes away, but the script now no longer works "pakage manager key 'nuget'" was not registerered...and I still get the mono.posix thing

Comment: do I need core 3.0?

Comment: Oh those pesky semicolons :) Well you need [F# 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5/#package-references-in-f-scripts) which goes along with .NET 5. I think some F# 5 can work without the latest framework, but even if so it would be a hack. Is .NET 5 a problem?

Comment: I don't think .net 5 is a problem...I'll have to give it a go